# AppClip AppStore Review Rejection - Spinner Spins Indefinitely

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, apple-appclips

I created a app that has a AppClip which will pull up a restaurant menu. The invocation URL is similar to "www.mydomain.com/restaurant/113", this will be launched via QR code.

I tested the AppClip on both Xcode build and TestFlight, also tested with AppClip local experience which all works fine on my device.
Basically I follow these 2 docs when testing the Clip. [link 1](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devbc57e2ec6) , [link 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2431/_index.html)

However when I submit the app to AppStore, I got rejection with the reason of "We tried again however we continue to see only the progress indicator clip was launched."

[image]

The review team wouldn't provide more information on how they launch the clip and how I could reproduce this issue. I couldn't reproduce this locally either following the AppClip test guide. if anyone have seen similar issue I appreciate your help.

Comment: This is just a guess but one should take into account that Apple always tests with slow or no network connection.

Comment: Thanks @matt, from what I can see from their reply, seems they can't even see my clip show up.

Comment: Yeah, it was a total guess. :(

Answer (score 0):

Apple suddenly approved the exact build without replying anything. So I guess it's a issue on their side.